# Given $\frac{1}{2x^3}$ find summation notation of Taylor series at $a=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

Having trouble with this problem.

> Given $$\frac{1}{2x^3}$$ find summation notation of Taylor series at $a=2$

[image]

Those are the first few terms in the Taylor Series, I'm just struggling to find the summation notation. Here's the series before multiplying the factorials.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the power series of $(1+x)^{-3}$, you can write $x=2+h$, and
$$\frac{1}{2x^3} = \frac{1}{2(2+h)^3} = \frac{1}{16}.\frac{1}{(1+h/2)^3}$$
and then use
$$(1+x)^{-3} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{-3}{n}x^n$$
and substitute $h/2$ for $x$.